# Django delete superuser

Tags: python, django

This may be a duplicate, but I couldn't find the question anywhere, so I'll go ahead and ask:

Is there a simple way to delete a superuser from the terminal, perhaps analogous to Django's `createsuperuser` command?

Comment: Amazingly - it looks like it's not a duplicate. I did a quick check...

Answer (score 139, accepted):

There's no built in command but you can easily do this from the shell:

```
> python manage.py shell
$ from django.contrib.auth.models import User
$ User.objects.get(username="joebloggs", is_superuser=True).delete()
```

Comment: Sounds like a silly question, but why! is there no in built command for that?

Comment: it isnt a silly question, let me know if you find an answer to that

Comment: In Django 1.11, it looks like this is still accurate except the first line should be `python manage.py shell`.

Answer (score 7):

In the case of a custom user model it would be:

```sh
python manage.py shell
```

```py
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
model = get_user_model()
model.objects.get(username="superjoe", is_superuser=True).delete()
```

Answer (score 4):

***An answer for people who did not use Django's User model instead substituted a Django custom user model.***

```
class ManagerialUser(BaseUserManager):
    """ This is a manager to perform duties such as CRUD(Create, Read,
     Update, Delete) """

    def create_user(self, email, name, password=None):
         """ This creates a admin user object """

         if not email:
             raise ValueError("It is mandatory to require an email!")

         if not name:
             raise ValueError("Please provide a name:")

         email = self.normalize_email(email=email)
         user = self.model(email=email, name=name)

         """ This will allow us to store our password in our database
         as a hash """
         user.set_password(password)
         user.save(using=self._db)

         return user


    def create_superuser(self, email, name, password):
         """ This creates a superuser for our Django admin interface"""

         user = self.create_user(email, name, password)
         user.is_superuser = True
         user.is_staff = True
         user.save(using=self._db)

         return user


class TheUserProfile(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    """ This represents a admin User in the system and gives specific permissions
 to this class. This class wont have staff permissions """

    # We do not want any email to be the same in the database.
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'

    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['name',]

    # CLASS POINTER FOR CLASS MANAGER
    objects = ManagerialUser()

    def get_full_name(self):
        """ This function returns a users full name """

        return self.name

    def get_short_name(self):
        """ This will return a short name or nickname of the admin user
        in the system. """

        return self.name

    def __str__(self):
        """ A dunder string method so we can see a email and or
        name in the database """

        return self.name + ' ' + self.email
```

***Now to delete a registered `SUPERUSER` in our system:***

```
python3 manage.py shell

>>>(InteractiveConsole)
>>>from yourapp.models import TheUserProfile
>>>TheUserProfile.objects.all(email="The email you are looking for", is_superuser=True).delete()
```

Comment: This led me down the right path, but for me it was objects.get(), not objects.all()

Answer (score 4):

No need to delete superuser...just create another superuser... You can create another superuser with same name as the previous one.
I have forgotten the password of the superuser so I create another superuser with the same name as previously.

Comment: This didn't work for me it reports with an error `Error: That username is already taken.`

Comment: @Youssof H. - same, did you find a solution/workaround

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple custom management command, to add in `myapp/management/commands/deletesuperuser.py`:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from django.core.management.base import CommandError


class Command(BaseCommand):

    def add_arguments(self, parser):
        parser.add_argument('username', type=str)

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(username=options['username'], is_superuser=True)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            raise CommandError("There is no superuser named {}".format(options['username']))

        self.stdout.write("-------------------")
        self.stdout.write("Deleting superuser {}".format(options.get('username')))
        user.delete()
        self.stdout.write("Done.")
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-management-commands/#accepting-optional-arguments

Answer (score 1):

A variation from @Timmy O'Mahony answer is to use the `shell_plus` (from `django_extensions`) to identify your User model automatically.

```
python manage.py shell_plus
```

```py
User.objects.get(
    username="joebloggs",
    is_superuser=True
).delete()
```

If the user email is unique, you can delete the user by email too.

```py
User.objects.get(
    email="joebloggs@email.com",
    is_superuser=True
).delete()
```

Answer (score -2):

There is no way to delete it from the Terminal (unfortunately), but you can delete it directly. Just log into the admin page, click on the user you want to delete, scroll down to the bottom and press delete.