# Can not delete superuser in django and a resulting error django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such column: infrastructure_profile.slug

Tags: django, django-models

I wanted to add a slug field to my model Profile (that extends the User model) after I had several profiles created, then an error appeared when reaching the profile page with the slug in the url saying :

```
Django OperationalError: no such column: infrastructure_profile.slug
```

so I looked here and saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53864200/5752406) answer

and it suggested I delete all my migrations files to restart the database , so I did

and then I got the same error , so I thought I should delete all the users I already have that didn't had the slug field already including the superuser.

so I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26713562/5752406) answer

and I got that error

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such column: infrastructure_profile.slug
```

any idea what's going on ?

**Edit**

My models.py contains the model Profile like so

```
class Profile(User):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, parent_link=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bio = models.TextField()
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, blank=True)
    avatar_thumbnail = ProcessedImageField(upload_to='images/',
                                            default='/images/default.png',
                                           processors=[ResizeToFill(300, 300)],
                                           format='JPEG',
                                           options={'quality': 60})
    location = models.TextField()
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
    contact_information = models.TextField()
    verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    counter = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print('self.username')
        print(self.user.username)
        self.slug = self.user.username
        super(Profile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('infrastructure:edit-user-profile', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})
```

Comment: Are you sure you ran the `python manage.py makemigrations && python manage.py migrate`?

Comment: you have to delete all the users and do remigration or delete the db itself and remigrate

Comment: @ShakibHossain Yes I am sure

Comment: @user6837382 I did that and got that problem https://stackoverflow.com/q/58891301/5752406

Comment: I couldn't do the first suggestion , that's what the question is for .. can not delete superuser , and when I did the second suggestion I got the linked problem @user6837382

Comment: Which db you are using?

Comment: @user6837382 sqlite3

Comment: Manually delete the db, either from the folder or from the editor and migrate again

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add model definitions.

Comment: @heemayl added the model

Answer (score 0):

Delete the db and delete all the files in the migration folder except__init__.py file in all your apps will work. After than do migration again

Comment: I already did that , nothing changed , I get the same problems

Answer (score 0):

I shouldn't have inherited Profile from the User model and I should have customized the user to 
following this answer instead

https://stackoverflow.com/a/58904426/5752406