# I get django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: auth_user.username for no apparent reason

Tags: python, django, django-authentication

I have a very weird situation

when I create the superuser at first I get no problem,

then when I run

```
python manage.py shell
```

and type

```
>>> from django.contrib.auth.models import User
>>> User.objects.all()
```

I get the following

```
<QuerySet [<User: >]>
```

a superuser with no username , and when I try to create a second superuser(even with a different username) because this one obviously can't be used , I get the error in the title

what happened to my app ? or what was new ? .. I deleted my database file and migration files and made a makemigrations and migrate commands

to know more about why I did that check [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58885867/5752406)

so how can I fix this ?

Comment: How do you construct a second user?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem by using the command createsuperuser