# Am I overriding the save method on the model in a wrong way in django?

Tags: django, django-models

I have a `Profile` model that extends the user model like so,

```
class Profile(User):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, parent_link=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, blank=True)
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print('self.username')
        print(self.username)
        self.slug = self.username
        super(Profile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

I am trying to create a slug field for my model , so I override the save method to include the slug as the username. The thing is, when I create a new user with the command `createsuperuser` and print out the username as you can see in the code, it doesn't show anything - it doesn't show the provided username. Could this be the reason why I am having [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58891301/5752406) ? And if so, how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're sure you don't want to have your user's profile data in a separate model with a `OneToOneField` back to Django's default `User`, then you should probably subclass `AbstractUser` and not `User`, as specified in the docs.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model

Consider this part :

> If you’re entirely happy with Django’s User model and you just want to add some additional profile information, you could simply subclass django.contrib.auth.models.AbstractUser and add your custom profile field [...]

(from https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-django-s-default-user)

Then you'd go like this:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.contrib.auth.models import UserManager
from django.utils.text import slugify
from django.db import models


class User(AbstractUser):
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, blank=True)

    objects = UserManager()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print('self.username')
        print(self.username)
        self.slug = slugify(self.username)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Then, define `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`,

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = "myapp.User"  # also, add 'myapp' to INSTALLED_APPS
```

Remember: you'll need to reference your User model like this (and this is how you should do it anyway, whether you customized that model or not):

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

User = get_user_model()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot this one worked for me , I wonder why the documentation is not as clear as your answer is , for example it doesn't mention neither the `get_user_model` thing nor the `objects=  UserManager() ` thing, I can't express how thankful I am though

Comment: I mean where can I find such information if I need to ?

Comment: Actually, everything is in the documentation. Django has a very complete doc, but it does take time to find your way through it. I usually skim though it, noting mentally that there's a chapter about this or that topic, then I go back. Or simply by googling :)

Comment: Do I have to use signals to relate the new customized User to the original User model? because I used to use signals with my Profile model to correspondingly be created with the User model , and now with these changes , I still have my signals and still naming the customized user Profile and the app is working just fine and I don't understand why, shouldn't there be a problem or something ?

Comment: Nope, the original `User` model (the Django one) will not be used anymore, it has been replaced by by the `AUTH_USER_MODEL = "myapp.User"` setting. It _is_ the model that will be used for users throughout your application. However, if you had a production database and introduced that change, you'll have to do a careful data migration yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Profile cannot inherit User but instead should inherit Model. And, for the creation of User to be able to create a corresponding row in a different table (Profile) and set the slug will involve the use of [signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/).

Answer (score 0):

You are overriding the save method correctly. You need to do more when you use the `createsuperuser` command.

```
from django.utils.text import slugify
from django.contrib.auth.models import UserManager


class CustomUserManager(UserManager):
    def _create_user(self, username, email, password, **extra_fields):
        username_slug = slugify(username)
        extra_fields.setdefault('slug', username_slug)
        super()._create_user(username, email, password, **extra_fields)


class Profile(User):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, parent_link=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print('self.username')
        print(self.username)
        self.slug = slugify(self.username)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    objects = CustomUserManager()
```

Comment: unfortunately the user is still stored with no username

Comment: I have now tested it and it works for me. Any new user you create (whether with the createsuperuser command or by calling profile_obj.save() will automatically generate a slug based on the username.)

Comment: I now realize that you do not want this Profile to be your User model. I tested this with the assumption that it was going to be equivalent to a User model but with a different name.