# AttributeError: Cutome User model object has no attribute 'password'

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a Profile model customizing the User model by having a one to one relationship to the User model, the code for the model is the following

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, parent_link=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bio = models.TextField()
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, blank=True)
    avatar_thumbnail = ProcessedImageField(upload_to='images/',
                                            default='/images/default.png',
                                           processors=[ResizeToFill(300, 300)],
                                           format='JPEG',
                                           options={'quality': 60})
    location = models.TextField()
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
    contact_information = models.TextField()
    verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    counter = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print('self.username')
        print(self.user.username)
        self.slug = self.user.username
        super(Profile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('infrastructure:edit-user-profile', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})
```

whenever I enter the shell with

```
python manage.py shell
```

and get the Profile queryset

```
Profile.objects.all()
```

I get the error

```
AttributeError: 'Profile' object has no attribute 'password'
```

and whenever I enter the admin panel and click on the Profiles section
I get the same error saying the same thing

what's wrong ?

my admin.py code

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
# Register your models here.
from . import models

class SubjectTagAdmin(admin.TabularInline):
    model = models.SubjectTag.tags.through

class TagAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines=[SubjectTagAdmin, ]

admin.site.register(models.Tag, TagAdmin)
admin.site.register(models.SubjectTag)
admin.site.register(models.Profile)
admin.site.register(models.Organization)
```

**EDIT**

Now I only get the error when I reach the UpdateView for the Profile or when I edit it from the admin panel

The complete Traceback from the view:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\connect\Desktop\The-Social-Work\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py", line 164, in __get__
    rel_obj = self.field.get_cached_value(instance)
  File "C:\Users\connect\Desktop\The-Social-Work\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\mixins.py", line 13, in get_cached_value
    return instance._state.fields_cache[cache_name]
KeyError: 'user'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\connect\Desktop\The-Social-Work\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\connect\Desktop\The-Social-Work\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\connect\Desktop\The-Social-Work\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\connect\Desktop\The-Social-Work\env\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 71, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\connect\Desktop\The-Social-Work\env\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 97, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\connect\Desktop\The-Social-Work\env\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py", line 189, in get
    self.object = self.get_object()
  File "C:\Users\connect\Desktop\The-Social-Work\infrastructure\views.py", line 31, in get_object
    if obj.user.username != self.request.user.username:
  File "C:\Users\connect\Desktop\The-Social-Work\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py", line 178, in __get__
    rel_obj = self.get_object(instance)
  File "C:\Users\connect\Desktop\The-Social-Work\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py", line 293, in get_object
    kwargs = {field: getattr(instance, field) for field in fields}
  File "C:\Users\connect\Desktop\The-Social-Work\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py", line 293, in <dictcomp>
    kwargs = {field: getattr(instance, field) for field in fields}
AttributeError: 'Profile' object has no attribute 'password'
```

the complete traceback from the admin panel

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\connect\Desktop\The-Social-Work\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py", line 164, in __get__
    rel_obj = self.field.get_cached_value(instance)
  File "C:\Users\connect\Desktop\The-Social-Work\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\mixins.py", line 13, in get_cached_value
    return instance._state.fields_cache[cache_name]
KeyError: 'user'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\connect\Desktop\The-Social-Work\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\connect\Desktop\The-Social-Work\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\connect\Desktop\The-Social-Work\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\connect\Desktop\The-Social-Work\env\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 71, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\connect\Desktop\The-Social-Work\env\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 97, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\connect\Desktop\The-Social-Work\env\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py", line 189, in get
    self.object = self.get_object()
  File "C:\Users\connect\Desktop\The-Social-Work\infrastructure\views.py", line 31, in get_object
    if obj.user.username != self.request.user.username:
  File "C:\Users\connect\Desktop\The-Social-Work\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py", line 178, in __get__
    rel_obj = self.get_object(instance)
  File "C:\Users\connect\Desktop\The-Social-Work\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py", line 293, in get_object
    kwargs = {field: getattr(instance, field) for field in fields}
  File "C:\Users\connect\Desktop\The-Social-Work\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py", line 293, in <dictcomp>
    kwargs = {field: getattr(instance, field) for field in fields}
AttributeError: 'Profile' object has no attribute 'password'
[17/Nov/2019 18:15:35] "GET /edit_usr_profile/amrshedou/ HTTP/1.1" 500 104918
[17/Nov/2019 18:20:00] "GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 5187
[17/Nov/2019 18:20:02] "GET /admin/infrastructure/profile/ HTTP/1.1" 200 4387
[17/Nov/2019 18:20:02] "GET /admin/jsi18n/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3223
[17/Nov/2019 18:20:04] "GET /admin/infrastructure/profile/1/change/ HTTP/1.1" 200 8276
[17/Nov/2019 18:20:04] "GET /admin/jsi18n/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3223
[17/Nov/2019 18:20:10] "POST /admin/infrastructure/profile/1/change/ HTTP/1.1" 200 8435
[17/Nov/2019 18:20:10] "GET /admin/jsi18n/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3223
[17/Nov/2019 18:20:14] "GET /admin/infrastructure/tag/add/?_to_field=id&_popup=1 HTTP/1.1" 200 10535
[17/Nov/2019 18:20:14] "GET /admin/jsi18n/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3223
[17/Nov/2019 18:20:15] "GET /static/admin/js/inlines.js HTTP/1.1" 200 13773
[17/Nov/2019 18:20:18] "POST /admin/infrastructure/tag/add/?_to_field=id&_popup=1 HTTP/1.1" 200 359
[17/Nov/2019 18:20:18] "GET /static/admin/js/popup_response.js HTTP/1.1" 200 569
self.username
Internal Server Error: /admin/infrastructure/profile/1/change/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\connect\Desktop\The-Social-Work\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py", line 164, in __get__
    rel_obj = self.field.get_cached_value(instance)
  File "C:\Users\connect\Desktop\The-Social-Work\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\mixins.py", line 13, in get_cached_value
    return instance._state.fields_cache[cache_name]
KeyError: 'user'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\connect\Desktop\The-Social-Work\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\connect\Desktop\The-Social-Work\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\connect\Desktop\The-Social-Work\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\connect\Desktop\The-Social-Work\env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 606, in wrapper
    return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\connect\Desktop\The-Social-Work\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 142, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\connect\Desktop\The-Social-Work\env\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py", line 44, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\connect\Desktop\The-Social-Work\env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py", line 223, in inner
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\connect\Desktop\The-Social-Work\env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 1637, in change_view
    return self.changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)
  File "C:\Users\connect\Desktop\The-Social-Work\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 45, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\connect\Desktop\The-Social-Work\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 142, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\connect\Desktop\The-Social-Work\env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 1522, in changeform_view
    return self._changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)
  File "C:\Users\connect\Desktop\The-Social-Work\env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 1561, in _changeform_view
    self.save_model(request, new_object, form, not add)
  File "C:\Users\connect\Desktop\The-Social-Work\env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 1088, in save_model
    obj.save()
  File "C:\Users\connect\Desktop\The-Social-Work\infrastructure\models.py", line 52, in save
    print(self.user.username)
  File "C:\Users\connect\Desktop\The-Social-Work\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py", line 178, in __get__
    rel_obj = self.get_object(instance)
  File "C:\Users\connect\Desktop\The-Social-Work\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py", line 293, in get_object
    kwargs = {field: getattr(instance, field) for field in fields}
  File "C:\Users\connect\Desktop\The-Social-Work\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py", line 293, in <dictcomp>
    kwargs = {field: getattr(instance, field) for field in fields}
AttributeError: 'Profile' object has no attribute 'password'
```

views.py

```
class ProfileUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = Profile
    fields= [
        'username',
        'bio',
        'avatar_thumbnail',
        'location',
        'tags',
        'contact_information'
        ]

    def get_object(self):
        obj = Profile.objects.get(slug = self.kwargs.get('slug'))
        if obj.user.username != self.request.user.username:
            raise exceptions.PermissionDenied()
        return obj

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ProfileUpdate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['tag_form'] = TagForm
        return context 

    def get_queryset(self):
        base_qs = super(ProfileUpdate, self).get_queryset()
        return base_qs.filter(username=self.request.user.username)
```

Comment: please show complete error traceback

Comment: @JPG Okay, I have done it

Answer (score 0):

I should have replaced the one to one relationship option to customizing the user to 
following this answer instead

https://stackoverflow.com/a/58904426/5752406