# I forgot my superuser username and password. How do I delete the superuser?

Tags: python-3.x, terminal, django-admin

I forgot my admin superuser username and password. How do I delete the superuser using the terminal or using django?

Comment: Does it help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26713443/django-delete-superuser

Comment: Please tell us what software you are using. We shouldn't have to read the tags and guess.